# Filter a column which is less than a certain value that is derived from another formula, then get the maximum value

Tags: excel-2013, powerpivot, dax

I have a table which contains grades of all students. Suppose I have a value `UpperLimit` which is derived from another formula, how to get the highest grade which is less than the `UpperLimit`?

Example:

```
Grade
-----
18
72
43
100
65
75
```

If the `UpperLimit` is 75 (after being calculated), then it should return 72, since 72 is the highest number below 75.

My idea is to filter the table/column first which is less than `UpperLimit`, then get the maximum value from it. Currently, my code is like this:

```
MAXX(
    FILTER(
        VALUES(Student[Grade]),
        Student[Grade] < [UpperLimit]
    ),
    Student[Grade]
)
```

However, it returns 100 instead (the highest *overall* value).

Could someone explain why it returns 100, and how to fix the formula in DAX?

Comment: I can give you the answer with a normal Excel formula.

Comment: Updated the question. I need the formula in DAX though.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew,

I would suggest using [disconnected slicer technique](http://www.powerpivotpro.com/2013/08/moving-averages-controlled-by-slicer/#more-7966). With this approach, I was then easily able to achieve your goal with this formula:

```
=CALCULATE(MAX(Grades[Grade]), FILTER(Grades, [Grade] < [Upper Limit Selected]))
```

Where [Upper Limit Selected] is a value returned by disconnected slicer. I have uploaded the [source file to my Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d6hlhx36pjs9ykm/Disconnected%20Slicer%20%26%20MAX.xlsx?dl=0) - let met know if this works for you.